# Configure Docker Desktop's run command

Tags: docker

Fairly basic question here: How do I specify which ports are exposed for a container through docker desktop (e.g. a command like docker run -d -p 5000:5000 image)? I have non-technical users so want to stay off the CLI if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you downloaded the image. Click on `run`

[image]

Expand `Optional settings`

[image]

And fill in the required configuration variables.

[image]

Comment: Wow right in front of me the whole time - thanks